# how do I ask vs how to ask

Tags: questions, infinitives, do-support

what is the difference between

> how do I ask

and

> how to ask

I am an Indian. **Basically asking question we have to use "do, does and did".** Please explain does `How to ask` make a question?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one question here. I completely understand your confusion as a non-native speaker. Because I used to make the same mistake! What we non-native speakers **must** learn is 'auxiliary verbs'.

Forget the sentences you quoted for a while.

Now, look at this sentence:

> How you do that?

Now, most Indians (including the 'early me'!) think that this forms a question. **But**, it is **not!**. Why? Because it doesn't have an *auxiliary verb* -**do**. But in India, we speak this quite often, and furthermore, the listener understands it easily because he's also Indian!

The question should be...

> How *do* you do that?

Do you see the added 'do' there? That's 'auxiliary verb' which is crucial for **making a sentence a question**. Why? Because, without double 'do's' it is **just a sentence** or maybe a part of sentence. Check this...

> This is **how you do that**.

Said that, an auxiliary verb is important (what you said -'do, does, did' etc) to form a question. Unfortunately all around me don't use it even in formal talking.

Now your sentences in concern.

> How do I ask?

...is a proper format of a question. 'Do' is an auxiliary verb.

> How to ask

is **also** valid, but it forms a sentence. Not a typical question.

> Here are the 10 ways on **how to ask** for help when in emergency 
>  **How to ask** a girl whether she needs a help

Not necessarily then end with a question mark.